# Make test failing when installing packages with CPAN on Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, perl, make, cpan

I'm trying to install Date::Manip::Date, which requires YAML::Syck. I'm running Cygwin on Windows XP.

Both packages fail their make tests. I have installed other packages sucessfully, such as Text::CSV, Text::CSV_XS and Text::CSV::Simple

I've tried installing both packages separately, and also together (i.e. 'yes' when it asks to prepend the dependency). I've run 'clean' on the packages before trying each different type of installation.

Finally, in a fit of frustration, I forced the installations (e.g. 'cpan -fi YAML::Syck') and, though the make test failed, the installation completed with apparentt success.

When running the script that requires Date::Manip::Date, I get the following error:

```
Not a HASH reference at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/Date/Manip/Base.pm line 1585, <DATA> line 496.
```

Here's the relevant bit from Base.pm

```
# This takes a list of words and creates a simple regexp which matches
# any of them.
#
# The first word in the list is the default way to express the word using
# a normal ASCII character set.
#
# The second word in the list is the default way to express the word using
# a locale character set. If it isn't defined, it defaults to the first word.
#
sub _rx_wordlist {
   my($self,$ele) = @_;

   if (exists $$self{'data'}{'lang'}{$ele}) {        # <--- Line 1585
      my @tmp = @{ $$self{'data'}{'lang'}{$ele} };

      $$self{'data'}{'wordlistA'}{$ele} = $tmp[0];
      if (defined $tmp[1]  &&  $tmp[1]) {
         $$self{'data'}{'wordlistL'}{$ele} = $tmp[1];
      } else {
         $$self{'data'}{'wordlistL'}{$ele} = $tmp[0];
      }

      my @tmp2;
      foreach my $tmp (@tmp) {
         push(@tmp2,"\Q$tmp\E")  if ($tmp);
      }
      @tmp2  = sort _sortByLength(@tmp2);

      $$self{'data'}{'rx'}{$ele} = join('|',@tmp2);

   } else {
      $$self{'data'}{'rx'}{$ele} = undef;
   }
}
```

This is what I'm guessing is the relevant portion of the script I'm calling.

```
my $date=new Date::Manip::Date;
if ($date->parse( join(' ', @ARGV) )) {
    die "Invalid Date '",join(' ', @ARGV),"'\n";
}
```

When installing, the errors were mostly along the lines of this:

```
t/1-basic.t ................... 1/11
#   Failed test at t/1-basic.t line 9.
#          got: 'ARRAY(0x101808a8)'
#     expected: 'Hello, world'
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 11.
t/1-basic.t ................... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
```

I can't actually reproduce the installation experience right now, because if I try to install now (after forcing them to install) it says they're up to date. However, I did copy the results from one of my attempts at installing YAML::Syck

```
cpan

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9402)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> install YAML::Syck
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Going to read '/home/IanToltz/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 21 Oct 2010 13:49:02 GMT
Running install for module 'YAML::Syck'
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.71)
Running make for A/AV/AVAR/YAML-Syck-1.15.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.47)
Checksum for /home/IanToltz/.cpan/sources/authors/id/A/AV/AVAR/YAML-Syck-1.15.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build for sizes
...................................................................---------DONE
DEL(1/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Archive-Extract-0.44-jD17oR
DEL(2/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Archive-Extract-0.44-jD17oR.yml
DEL(3/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Archive-Tar-1.68-ZanOl9
DEL(4/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Attribute-Handlers-0.88-ktJN8R
DEL(5/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Attribute-Handlers-0.88-ktJN8R.yml
DEL(6/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/AutoLoader-5.70-mbqLN3
DEL(7/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/AutoLoader-5.70-mbqLN3.yml
DEL(8/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/B-Debug-1.16-IPCuri.yml
DEL(9/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/B-Debug-1.16-IPCuri
DEL(10/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/B-Lint-1.12-rtXniH
DEL(11/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/CPAN-Checksums-2.05-JT0jSU
DEL(12/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/CPAN-Checksums-2.05-JT0jSU.yml
DEL(13/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Devel-Autoflush-0.05-MPLGOW
DEL(14/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Devel-Autoflush-0.05-MPLGOW.yml
DEL(15/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/CPAN-Reporter-1.1803-HVkllO
DEL(16/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/CPAN-Reporter-1.1803-HVkllO.yml
DEL(17/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/CPANPLUS-0.9007-kKDfp6
DEL(18/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Module-Load-Conditional-0.38-6tOWTx
DEL(19/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Module-CoreList-2.39-Zd1MbW
DEL(20/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/CPANPLUS-Dist-Build-0.48-9267IC
DEL(21/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Class-ISA-0.36-pce_2V.yml
DEL(22/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Class-ISA-0.36-pce_2V
DEL(23/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Compress-Raw-Bzip2-2.031-HYfPs6
DEL(24/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.030-udixOx
DEL(25/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Config-Tiny-2.13-vJbuZv
DEL(26/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Config-Tiny-2.13-vJbuZv.yml
DEL(27/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Data-Dumper-2.128-oZXgLr.yml
DEL(28/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Data-Dumper-2.128-oZXgLr
DEL(29/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Digest-MD5-2.51-zYRPFt
DEL(30/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Digest-MD5-2.51-zYRPFt.yml
DEL(31/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Digest-SHA-5.48-zX__j_.yml
DEL(32/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Digest-SHA-5.48-zX__j_
DEL(33/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/Encode-2.40-nQKQqP
DEL(34/34): /home/IanToltz/.cpan/build/ExtUtils-CBuilder-0.2703-2hUQU7
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.52)
YAML-Syck-1.15/
YAML-Syck-1.15/Syck.xs
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/parent.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Test/
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Test/Builder/
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Test/Builder/IO/
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Test/Builder/IO/Scalar.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Test/Builder/Module.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Test/Builder.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Test/More.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Module/
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Module/Install.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Module/Install/
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Module/Install/Include.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Module/Install/Base.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Module/Install/Metadata.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Module/Install/Compiler.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Module/Install/Fetch.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Module/Install/WriteAll.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Module/Install/Can.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Module/Install/Makefile.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/Module/Install/Win32.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/inc/PerlIO.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/gram.h
YAML-Syck-1.15/gram.c
YAML-Syck-1.15/perl_common.h
YAML-Syck-1.15/syck_st.h
YAML-Syck-1.15/ppport_math.h
YAML-Syck-1.15/README
YAML-Syck-1.15/emitter.c
YAML-Syck-1.15/Makefile.PL
YAML-Syck-1.15/node.c
YAML-Syck-1.15/syck.h
YAML-Syck-1.15/META.yml
YAML-Syck-1.15/syck_st.c
YAML-Syck-1.15/syck_.c
YAML-Syck-1.15/bytecode.c
YAML-Syck-1.15/ppport.h
YAML-Syck-1.15/handler.c
YAML-Syck-1.15/token.c
YAML-Syck-1.15/ppport_sort.h
YAML-Syck-1.15/COPYING
YAML-Syck-1.15/MANIFEST
YAML-Syck-1.15/implicit.c
YAML-Syck-1.15/Changes
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/json-refs.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/json-newline.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/json-loadfile.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/json-basic.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/yaml-alias.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/2-scalars.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/yaml-tie.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/4-perl_tag_scheme.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/yaml-blessed-ref.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/json-numbers.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/json-indent.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/json-crlf.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/json-null.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/json-empty.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/11-loadfile.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/12-dumpfile.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/yaml-str-colon-first.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/bug/
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/bug/rt-54167.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/bug/rt-49404-double_free.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/json-minus.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/TestYAML.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/leak.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/json-circular-ref.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/3-objects.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/1-basic.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/json-singlequote.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/t/yaml-implicit-warnings.t
YAML-Syck-1.15/perl_syck.h
YAML-Syck-1.15/lib/
YAML-Syck-1.15/lib/JSON/
YAML-Syck-1.15/lib/JSON/Syck.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/lib/YAML/
YAML-Syck-1.15/lib/YAML/Loader/
YAML-Syck-1.15/lib/YAML/Loader/Syck.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/lib/YAML/Syck.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/lib/YAML/Dumper/
YAML-Syck-1.15/lib/YAML/Dumper/Syck.pm
YAML-Syck-1.15/COMPATIBILITY
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)

  CPAN.pm: Going to build A/AV/AVAR/YAML-Syck-1.15.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for YAML::Syck
cp lib/JSON/Syck.pm blib/lib/JSON/Syck.pm
cp lib/YAML/Loader/Syck.pm blib/lib/YAML/Loader/Syck.pm
cp lib/YAML/Dumper/Syck.pm blib/lib/YAML/Dumper/Syck.pm
cp lib/YAML/Syck.pm blib/lib/YAML/Syck.pm
gcc-4 -c  -I. -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g3 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.15\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.15\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/CORE"   bytecode.c
gcc-4 -c  -I. -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g3 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.15\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.15\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/CORE"   emitter.c
gcc-4 -c  -I. -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g3 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.15\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.15\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/CORE"   gram.c
gcc-4 -c  -I. -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g3 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.15\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.15\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/CORE"   handler.c
gcc-4 -c  -I. -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g3 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.15\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.15\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/CORE"   implicit.c
gcc-4 -c  -I. -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g3 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.15\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.15\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/CORE"   node.c
gcc-4 -c  -I. -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g3 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.15\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.15\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/CORE"   syck_.c
gcc-4 -c  -I. -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g3 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.15\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.15\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/CORE"   syck_st.c
gcc-4 -c  -I. -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g3 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.15\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.15\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/CORE"   token.c
/usr/bin/perl.exe "-Iinc" /usr/lib/perl5/5.10/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/lib/perl5/5.10/ExtUtils/typemap  Syck.xs > Syck.xsc && mv Syck.xsc Syck.c
gcc-4 -c  -I. -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g3 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.15\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.15\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/CORE"   Syck.c
rm -f blib/arch/auto/YAML/Syck/Syck.dll
g++-4  --shared  -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--stack,8388608 -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector bytecode.o emitter.o gram.o handler.o implicit.o node.o syck_.o syck_st.o token.o Syck.o  -o blib/arch/auto/YAML/Syck/Syck.dll   \
          /usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/CORE/cygperl5_10.dll          \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/YAML/Syck/Syck.dll
test -s Syck.bs && cp Syck.bs blib/arch/auto/YAML/Syck/Syck.bs && \
          chmod 644 blib/arch/auto/YAML/Syck/Syck.bs
make: [blib/arch/auto/YAML/Syck/Syck.dll] Error 1 (ignored)
Manifying blib/man3/JSON.Syck.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/YAML.Syck.3pm
  AVAR/YAML-Syck-1.15.tar.gz
  make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'inc', ' blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t t/*/*.t
t/1-basic.t ................... 1/11
#   Failed test at t/1-basic.t line 9.
#          got: 'ARRAY(0x101808a8)'
#     expected: 'Hello, world'
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 11.
t/1-basic.t ................... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/11 subtests
t/11-loadfile.t ............... 1/12
#   Failed test 'LoadFile(*DATA) works'
#   at t/11-loadfile.t line 21.
#          
#     expected: 'a simple scalar'

#   Failed test 'LoadFile(\*DATA) works'
#   at t/11-loadfile.t line 27.
#          got: 'ARRAY(0x10184c50)'
#     expected: 'a simple scalar'

#   Failed test 'LoadFile works with file names'
#   at t/11-loadfile.t line 46.
#          got: 'ARRAY(0x1026c638)'
#     expected: 'a simple scalar'

#   Failed test 'LoadFile works with IO::File'
#   at t/11-loadfile.t line 52.
#          got: 'ARRAY(0x102be2d0)'
#     expected: 'a simple scalar'

#   Failed test 'LoadFile works with indirect filehandles'
#   at t/11-loadfile.t line 61.
#          got: 'ARRAY(0x102be318)'
#     expected: 'a simple scalar'

#   Failed test 'LoadFile works with ordinary filehandles'
#   at t/11-loadfile.t line 69.
#          got: 'ARRAY(0x102be2d0)'
#     expected: 'a simple scalar'

#   Failed test 'LoadFile works with glob refs'
#   at t/11-loadfile.t line 77.
#          got: 'ARRAY(0x1026cda0)'
#     expected: 'a simple scalar'

#   Failed test 'LoadFile works with in-memory files'
#   at t/11-loadfile.t line 87.
#          got: 'ARRAY(0x102792d8)'
#     expected: 'a simple scalar'
# Looks like you failed 8 tests of 12.
t/11-loadfile.t ............... Dubious, test returned 8 (wstat 2048, 0x800)
Failed 8/12 subtests
t/12-dumpfile.t ............... ok
t/2-scalars.t ................. 1/134
#   Failed test at t/2-scalars.t line 6.
#          got: 'ARRAY(0x101db920)'
#     expected: '42'
Not a SCALAR reference at t/2-scalars.t line 9.
# Looks like you planned 134 tests but ran 4.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 4 run.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 4.
t/2-scalars.t ................. Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 131/134 subtests
t/3-objects.t ................. 1/48
#   Failed test 'ref - !!perl/hash:foo'
#   at t/3-objects.t line 12.
#          got: 'ARRAY'
#     expected: 'foo'
Not a HASH reference at t/3-objects.t line 13.
# Looks like you planned 48 tests but ran 3.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 3 run.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 3.
t/3-objects.t ................. Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 46/48 subtests
t/4-perl_tag_scheme.t ......... 1/18
#   Failed test at t/4-perl_tag_scheme.t line 76.
#          got: 'ARRAY'
#     expected: 'HASH'
Not a HASH reference at t/4-perl_tag_scheme.t line 77.
# Looks like you planned 18 tests but ran 11.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 11 run.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 11.
t/4-perl_tag_scheme.t ......... Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 8/18 subtests
t/bug/rt-49404-double_free.t .. 1/4
#   Failed test at t/bug/rt-49404-double_free.t line 17.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[0] = ARRAY(0x10209ec8)
#     $expected->[0] = HASH(0x10043af0)

#   Failed test at t/bug/rt-49404-double_free.t line 24.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[0] = ARRAY(0x10209ec8)
#     $expected->[0] = HASH(0x10043af0)
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 4.
t/bug/rt-49404-double_free.t .. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 2/4 subtests
t/bug/rt-54167.t .............. ok
t/json-basic.t ................ ok
t/json-circular-ref.t ......... ok
t/json-crlf.t ................. ok
t/json-empty.t ................ ok
t/json-indent.t ............... ok
t/json-loadfile.t ............. ok
t/json-minus.t ................ ok
t/json-newline.t .............. ok
t/json-null.t ................. ok
t/json-numbers.t .............. ok
t/json-refs.t ................. ok
t/json-singlequote.t .......... ok
t/leak.t ...................... ok
t/yaml-alias.t ................ 1/14
#   Failed test 'array with anchor'
#   at t/yaml-alias.t line 11.
#          got: '---
# -
#   - &1 {}
#
#   - *1
# '
#     expected: '---
# - &1 {}
#
# - *1
# '

#   Failed test 'touched array with anchor'
#   at t/yaml-alias.t line 15.
#          got: '---
# -
#   - &1 {}
#
#   - *1
# - xyz
# '
#     expected: '---
# - {}
#
# - xyz
# '

#   Failed test 'hash with anchor'
#   at t/yaml-alias.t line 21.
#          got: '---
# -
#   abc: &1 {}
#
#   def: *1
# '
#     expected: '---
# abc: &1 {}
#
# def: *1
# '
Not a HASH reference at t/yaml-alias.t line 24.
# Looks like you planned 14 tests but ran 3.
# Looks like you failed 3 tests of 3 run.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 3.
t/yaml-alias.t ................ Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 14/14 subtests
t/yaml-blessed-ref.t .......... ok
t/yaml-implicit-warnings.t .... ok
t/yaml-str-colon-first.t ...... Not a HASH reference at t/yaml-str-colon-first.t line 11.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 before it could output anything.
t/yaml-str-colon-first.t ...... Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 129/129 subtests
t/yaml-tie.t .................. ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/1-basic.t                 (Wstat: 256 Tests: 11 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  3
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/11-loadfile.t             (Wstat: 2048 Tests: 12 Failed: 8)
  Failed tests:  1-8
  Non-zero exit status: 8
t/2-scalars.t               (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 4 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  3
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 134 tests but ran 4.
t/3-objects.t               (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 3 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  3
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 48 tests but ran 3.
t/4-perl_tag_scheme.t       (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 11 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  11
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 18 tests but ran 11.
t/bug/rt-49404-double_free.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 4 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  2, 4
  Non-zero exit status: 2
t/json-basic.t              (Wstat: 0 Tests: 104 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   81-82, 85-86, 93-94, 97-98
t/yaml-alias.t              (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 3 Failed: 3)
  Failed tests:  1-3
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 14 tests but ran 3.
t/yaml-str-colon-first.t    (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 129 tests but ran 0.
Files=26, Tests=264,  8 wallclock secs ( 0.16 usr  0.03 sys +  4.46 cusr  1.85 csys =  6.49 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 8/26 test programs. 17/264 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  AVAR/YAML-Syck-1.15.tar.gz
  make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports AVAR/YAML-Syck-1.15.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 AVAR/YAML-Syck-1.15.tar.gz                   : make_test NO

cpan[2]>
```

Any help would be appreciated! I'm at my wit's end!

Answer (score 2):

I have found that trying to use CPAN with cygwin is more bother than it is worth. I ended up ignoring cygwin's perl. I installed [Strawberry perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) and told cygwin to use that instead.

It's not perfect but fails to build **a lot less** CPAN modules than the native cygwin perl.

Comment: I gave that a try, but ran into issues getting Strawberry perl working correctly with cygwin. It worked intermittently, and did seem better, though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting the script working by copying a coworker's lib/perl5 folder. Not an actual solution to the problem, but the important thing is I can run the scripts I need to now. :/

Answer (score 0):

1. Report bug here: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=YAML-Syck
2. Try installing an older version: cpan TODDR/YAML-Syck-1.14.tar.gz